# Handling Larger number of category label in text classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn

In the current problem I am working on I am running text classification against ~16 possible variables.

If we assume there's equal number of every label our baseline would be `1/16 = 6.25%`. Using scikit learn, TF-IDF, ngrams and running text normalization the best results I am yielding so far are (without running gridsearch on the parameters):

- 52% for SGDClassifier
- 49% for RandomForestClassifier
- 49% for DecisionTreeClassifier
- 38% for MultinomialNaiveBayes

Not the best results for the final product but already a huge improvement on the baseline.

What are better approaches to improving the results?

One idea is to add a label and a sub-label, break the 16 into 4 groups and then run 2 models, one against the 4 major groups, and a second against the 4 minor groups.

Other approaches can include SVMClassifier, KNN, OnevsRestClassifier.

What is better approach to dealing with an array of labels for text classification to try and improve upon a 52% accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

[Doc2vec](https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf) might help. Embed each document into a high dimensional space. Then use a classification algorithm (e.g., k-nearest neighbors) on the created vectors.  [Gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim) is a Python package for [doc2vec](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/tutorials.md#tutorials).